# Kubernetes/Airflow Celery worker task fails with SigKill 9 error but no explanation (guessing OOME?)

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I am testing out Airflow on Kubernetes. Currently, I am running a simple DAG and purposefully trying to crash it to see what happens by running a memory-intensive task. My process queries a very large table and I'm trying to generate an Out Of Memory (OOM) error. I know it's happening because the task fails but the only logs I'm able to see give a vague error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/venvuydlj38n/bin/python', '/tmp/venvuydlj38n/script.py', '/tmp/venvuydlj38n/script.in', '/tmp/venvuydlj38n/script.out', '/tmp/venvuydlj38n/string_args.txt']' died with <Signals.SIGKILL: 9>.
```

This is the only thing I see. Nothing in Kubernetes tells me why either. The pod doesn't restart and I don't see anything on `kubectl get events`. I don't understand why Kubernetes isn't evicting the Pod. From the Kubernetes documentation, Kubernetes should kill this pod and reschedule it but it doesn't look like it's happening - yet my process still gets the SigKill 9 error. At this point I know it's an OOME, however I want to find the logs that will tell confirm that. If I get Sigkill 9 error some other reason I want to know.

Some other info: I set my Celery worker to have a 2GB resource limit.

Comment: Any OOMKills are registered as a kubernetes `Event` and are also shown in the `status.containerStatuses[0].lastState.terminated.reason` field for the Pod

Comment: Do you have any updates on the issue?

Comment: @EduardMukans sorry no update!

Comment: There is a `killed_task_cleanup_time` configuration parameter. Try to increase its value. I tried, it looks better. The parameter can be set via env var `AIRFLOW__CORE__KILLED_TASK_CLEANUP_TIME`. More info: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#killed-task-cleanup-time

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50632

and this article:
https://medium.com/back-market-engineering/a-story-of-kubernetes-celery-resource-and-a-rabbit-ec2ef9e37e9f

> When a container consumes more memory than its limit, the OOM Killer
> sends a SIGKILL (signal number 9) to one of its processes.
>
> If the container runs only one process, as it is often advised, the
> container will then exit with the same exit code. K8s will see this
> and report it, marking the container as OOMKilled. If, however, there
> are multiple processes running on the container, as is the case here
> with our Celery server and its 4 worker children processes, the
> SIGKILL may target any of those children. The Celery server will
> notice it

Answer (score 0):

To check if the pod was killed with OOM you can run `kubectl describe` on a resource:

```
$ kubectl describe <pod_name>

...
   State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 10 Oct 2019 11:14:13 +0200
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Thu, 10 Oct 2019 11:04:03 +0200
      Finished:     Thu, 10 Oct 2019 11:14:11 +0200
...
```

Comment: In my case the pod wasn't always showing this Reason. perhaps it's fixed with newer K8s versions. This was tested at the time on v1.15-v.1.17 I believe